# Run unit tests in developer command prompt

Tags: c#, unit-testing, command-line, mstest

I've created a project in VS 2017 with a single class copied from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx)
    .

```
namespace BankAccountNS
{
    /// <summary>   
    /// Bank Account demo class.   
    /// </summary>   
    public class BankAccount
    {
        public const string DebitAmountExceedsBalanceMessage = "Debit amount exceeds balance";
        public const string DebitAmountLessThanZeroMessage = "Debit amount less than zero";
        private string m_customerName;
        private double m_balance;
        private bool m_frozen = false;

        private BankAccount()
        { }

        public BankAccount(string customerName, double balance)
        {
            m_customerName = customerName;
            m_balance = balance;
        }

        public string CustomerName
        {
            get { return m_customerName; }
        }

        public double Balance
        {
            get { return m_balance; }
        }

        public void Debit(double amount)
        {
            if (m_frozen)
            {
                throw new Exception("Account frozen");
            }

            if (amount > m_balance)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount", amount, DebitAmountExceedsBalanceMessage);
            }

            if (amount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount", amount, DebitAmountLessThanZeroMessage);
            }

            m_balance -= amount;
        }

        public void Credit(double amount)
        {
            if (m_frozen)
            {
                throw new Exception("Account frozen");
            }

            if (amount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
            }

            m_balance += amount;
        }

        private void FreezeAccount()
        {
            m_frozen = true;
        }

        private void UnfreezeAccount()
        {
            m_frozen = false;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            BankAccount ba = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", 11.99);

            ba.Credit(5.77);
            ba.Debit(11.22);
            Console.WriteLine("Current balance is ${0}", ba.Balance);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've created a project for unit tests with single class and two test methods

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using BankAccountNS;
using System;

namespace BankTests
{
[TestClass()]
public class BankAccountTests
{        
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Debit_WithValidAmount_UpdatesBalance()
    {
        // arrange  
        double beginningBalance = 11.99;
        double debitAmount = 4.55;
        double expected = 7.44;
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", beginningBalance);

        // act  
        account.Debit(debitAmount);

        // assert  
        double actual = account.Balance;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, 0.001, "Account not debited correctly");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void Debit_WhenAmountIsMoreThanBalance_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRange()
    {
        // arrange  
        double beginningBalance = 11.99;
        double debitAmount = 20.0;
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", beginningBalance);

        // act  
        try
        {
            account.Debit(debitAmount);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            // assert  
            StringAssert.Contains(e.Message, BankAccount.DebitAmountExceedsBalanceMessage);
            return;
        }
        Assert.Fail("No exception was thrown.");
    }
}
```

It works well in VS, but when I try to run the same in console it returns

> No tests to execute.

[image]

I checked shared solutions from the previous posts, but unfortunately it doesn't help to run the tests. Can anybody help me with the issue please?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in versioning. Tests run in DCP for VS2015. I'm not sure how to fix it for the VS2017, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the exceptions of the built-in Test explorer, but I do use this framework with a different test runner, it is called smartrunner.
Why don't you try Typemock's [Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page/), it has the [TmockRunner](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Frunningtestsintmockrunner.htm) which can trigger tests from the command line and it has a full support for exceptions/errors like yours. It has a free trial so in case my suggestion doesnt work, no harm was done.
It will work for you for 100% because of the integration with MSTest frameworkefork, so you won't need to change anything in your code.